# Toggle 2 divs with 2 links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jquery and here's what I'm trying to do:

I have two links: link1 - link2
And 2 divs: div1, div2

What I would like to do:

If you click on link1 it slideDown the div1, if you click on link1 again, it slideUp div1
BUT
If you click on link1 and then on link2 I want the div1 to slideUp and then slideDown the div2

Here's the code that I was playing with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#div1").hide();
   $("#div2").hide();
   $('.link1').click(function(){
       $("#div2").slideUp();
       $("#div1").slideToggle();
   });
   $('.link2').click(function(){
       $("#div1").slideUp();
       $("#div2").slideToggle();
   });

});
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML for this?

Comment: Please share your html to take a look, it's not clear at all for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/dJLK3/1/

If so, look at the documentation for the animate functions like, [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).  There you can see how callbacks work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/mNyeS/)**

Actually your code works fine. Currently I have applied as class.

### HTML:

```
<div class="link1">Link1</div>
<div class="link2">Link2</div>

<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="div2">DIV2</div>
​
```

### JS:

```
$(".div1").hide();
$(".div2").hide();
$('.link1').click(function(){
    $(".div2").slideUp();
    $(".div1").slideToggle();
});
$('.link2').click(function(){
$(".div1").slideUp();
$(".div2").slideToggle();
});​
```

Comment: AS you can see on your demo, the div slides over the last one. I would like to first close one and than open the other.